# How did Gale and Katniss find out they could escape through the fence?

Tags: the-hunger-games

We know Gale and Katniss have been leaving the District 12 boundaries for awhile to hunt because they have established trade agreements with other citizens. How did they discover that it was safe to sneak out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Katniss learned from her father, who probably learned by watching the fence and realizing it wasn't always on. Gale probably learned in a similar way, from some adult figure in his life, who paid very close attention to the wall.